# Does Deadshot ever remove his mask in canon?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, dc-animated-universe, suicide-squad, suicide-squad-2016

In the new [Suicide Squad](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1386697/) pictures, [Deadshot](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Deadshot) (Will Smith) is not wearing his mask.

[image]

Whether in [comics](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/youngjustice/images/4/46/Deadshot.png/revision/latest?cb=20130107210026) or [animated TV shows](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/smallville/images/a/a3/Batman_Rouges_Deadshot_DCAU_Deadshot.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20121018160316), I've never seen Deadshot without his mask.

Does Deadshot remove his mask often / ever in canon?

Comment: They're paying a lot for that face, might as well use it

Comment: Deadshot's in that photo? All I see is a sexy Harley Quinn and a terrible-looking Killer Croc.

Comment: In the race between showing the face of the comics vs the face you're paying for, he's waaaaaaay behind Iron Man.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know Floyd Lawton AKA Deadshot has never had a problem taking off his mask in the comics.

[image]

Or in the cartoons.(Justice League Unlimited: Task Force X)

[image]

Comment: And in Arrow on TV, he doesn't even wear a mask. Just an eye piece.